Any modern Firefox fork that quickly adopts all functionality updates while stripping restrictive changes?
Something similar to what devuan is to debian?
Examples would be maintaining the option to load unpacked extensions, alsa support, etc. right now people use workarounds to address these, but those complicate the setup, are unreliable in the long run and common sense tells us that the trend with FF becoming more restrictive and less customizable will continue and it will get harder to do this.
For example, right now I'm using FF Developer Edition to be able to load addons from files, and mount xpi with fuse to be able to edit the source directly, but:

if i introduce a syntax error in the manifest, firefox simply deletes the extension;
having a directory mounted with fuse from a xpi file in a git repo seems like asking for problems with git too

FF is still very customizable, but it won't surprise anyone if tomorrow user.js or userChrome.css are no longer supported.
I'm aware of Pale Moon, but, as most developers, need all the latest web technologies. And using just the engine to create own browser would be too big of a work.

Welcome darkdiatel!  I'm glad you were able to find our community!
